# Short-story about a boy's obsession with a video game about war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, video-games, computers

I have been searching for so long now for the title of a short-story I read in the late 1990s, I think. Possibly early 2000s. The plot goes along something like this. There is a boy, I think he may have just recently graduated from college. He starts to play a computer game. It is a war game that he has to program the correct amount of weapons to use to be able to win the war.

He becomes obsessed with the game as he just can't work out what the answer could be and he tries a multitude of numbers. I think he has a girlfriend that ends up walking out on him due to his obsession. His world falls apart around him because of the game (it may or may not actually be real but I could be confusing that with Ender's Game). It turns out that the correct answer is zero because there are (surprise surprise) no winners in war.

I thought this was a Stephen King short story but I have trawled through the list of every SK short story ever written and I cannot find it anything that even closely resembles this one. It's **not** the movie/book WarGame.

Comment: I'm not sure how close the book is to the movie, but there is [a book for WarGames](http://www.amazon.com/War-Games-David-Bischoff/dp/0440193877). Again, I'm not sure about the differences between the book and movie, but It might be more like what you're describing.

Comment: HI, thanks for your response. Unfortunately no, it's not Wargames. I've looked at that one extensively as it's the closest one I can find to it. But, alas, not it.

Comment: Sorry. It's definitely a short-story. It was in a collection of short-stories, an anthology. Which is where the "book" comes into it. Sorry. Should have been clearer on that. It's the title of the short-story I am after, not the anthology per se. But, if someone does happen to know the short-story I guess it would be also reasonable to assume they would know the collection in which it is found.

Comment: I have edited to remove book reference.